# I'm using silk central and silk 4j for automation test for website

Tags: java

I'm using silk central and silk 4j for automation test for website, but i meet a problem that i can't set for background process while it does a test..i have already tried to open window >>preference >> and check "always the run in background". any one have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Since Silk Test version 17.5 it's possible to run tests in the background with all browsers except Internet Explorer.